# AWS Cognito Unknown Error on signin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm getting an Unkown Error when I'm trying to signin to Cognito in AWS using android ( java ) code.

```
 public void SignIn(String phoneNumber) {

    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

    // Create a CognitoUserPool object to refer to your user pool
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(_context, poolId, _clientId,
            _clientSecret, clientConfiguration);

    CognitoUser user = userPool.getUser(phoneNumber);

    // Callback handler for the sign-in process
    AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession) {
            // Sign-in was successful, cognitoUserSession will contain tokens for the user
            Token = cognitoUserSession.getAccessToken();

        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(userId, _password, null);

            // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);

            // Allow the sign-in to continue
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {
            // Multi-factor authentication is required; get the verification code from user
            multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.setMfaCode("123");
            // Allow the sign-in process to continue
            multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            // Sign-in failed, check exception for the cause
            Log.d("error:", exception.getMessage());
            LoginController loginController = new LoginController(_this);
            loginController.NavigateToLogin();

        }
    };

    // Sign in the user
    user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);

}
```

I've accepted all the default roles in IAM.

Signup and confirmation of the email works fine. it's just when I want to signin after   authenticationContinuation.continueTask(); it's showing unknown error. any ideas? suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a wrong poolid duh!
there is a pool id in federation pool as well and I was using that instead of the one in user pool